# Determining width of paths

Tags: image-processing

I have an image, like the one below that has different paths. I want to be able to detect the thin parts of these paths and highlight them. What is the best way to go about this?
[image: Image containing paths]

Answer (score 6):

Just an idea that might work. Let original image be $I_0$. Erode just enough to remove the thin lines, then dilate back to obtain $I_1$. Afterwards, obtain the difference of the $I_0$ and $I_1$.

Comment: Thinning until 1px lines appears is skeletonization, and it works ;)

Answer (score 1):

I got a bit confused on your question. Are you looking for the paths that are thin? or are you trying to make the paths thin?

- Maybe this paper about [Stroke Width Transform](http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~cernyad2/TextCaptchaPdf/Detecting%20Text%20in%20Natural%20Scenes%20with%20Stroke%20Width%20Transform.pdf) can help you.
- I would also like to suggest doing edge detection first. Then you compute the distance from one edge to another, both on X and Y directions, and then saving the smallest distance in each pixel of the path. To highlight the paths you will look for the smallest values saved on each pixel of the paths.

I hope this helps.